# youtube iframe api- sound only play back on android

Tags: html, video, youtube

I am using a web based html5 mobile app builder (tiggzi).  I am using the youtube iframe api.  When I install my app on my android devices the embedded video displays the placeholder image just fine.  On my nexus 7 with android 4.2.2 if I hit play I hear the sound but do not see the video (black).  If I hit the full screen I see the video play ok.  On my android 4.0.4 bionic phone I see the video placeholder image but play just shows black and full screen does not respond (ultimately app crashes).  On my desktop machine testing my app in chrome video plays fine.

my html:
`<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/u1zgFlCw8Aw" frameborder="0">
</iframe>`

Question is, how do I get video to play correctly as embedded in and html5 mobile app for both android 2+ and iphone/ipad?  I thought the iframe api would work but it still falls back to flash which appears to be the problem in my case.